# SignalR errors appearing in ELMAH when not using SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, elmah

I am getting errors relating to SignalR appearing in ELMAH. I am not using SignalR and I am running on Localhost. The solution is a MVC5 internet app. What is the cause of this and how can I stop this ?

> The controller for path '/signalr/negotiate' was not found or does not implement IController.

System.Web.HttpException
The controller for path '/signalr/negotiate' was not found or does not implement IController.

System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The controller for path '/signalr/negotiate' was not found or does not implement IController.
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2013 this may be caused by the new Browser Link feature. Try [disabling it](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link#disabling) and see if the error goes away.

Comment: Is there a way to remedy the problem without disabling browser link? If I installed SignalR would that remove the problem ?

Comment: I don't know what that solution might be. I also cannot remember the circumstances of my browser link problems. It may have had something to do with clearing something in web.config like modules or handlers, but I am not sure. If you are clearing things like that you might try replacing the single clear with specific remove elements.

Comment: I found Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime assembly 2.1.0.0 here:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Page Inspector\

I get "Invalid module qualification" squiggly for this assembly!!!

<add name="FilterForBrowserLink" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Tracing.PageInspectorHttpModule, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /> If this assembly can be recognized then I can use intellisense to enter ".Tracing" however it is not loaded

Answer (score 5):

I resolved this, without disabling Browser Link, by implementing the following in my `Web.config`:

```
<elmah>
    <errorFilter>
        <test>
            <jscript>
                <expression>
                    <![CDATA[
                    // @assembly mscorlib
                    // @assembly System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
                    // @import System.IO
                    // @import System.Web

                    $.Context.Request.UserAgent.match('/*+/arterySignalR/ping')                      
                    ]]>
                </expression>
            </jscript>
        </test>
    </errorFilter>
</elmah>
```